# How do i bind a react component to the database state?

Tags: django, reactjs

I want to bind the state of a react component to a backend server running on Django. What i am trying to achieve is an ajax call that constantly updates the state of the component, however, constantly making an api call after every couple of seconds might have an impact on the performance of the application and hence, i am looking for a better way to achieve the same.

Comment: Is your concern updating the DB when you update the frontend? Or is your concern updating one user's frontend when another user changes the DB?

Comment: The latter i'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two possible solutions -- polling and websockets. Polling means making a call at a specified interval asking what's changed. That's easy, but as you said, can be inefficient. Websockets involve the server sending push notifications to the browser saying when something changes.

[This site](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-io-node-js-react/) gives an introduction on how to use websockets for what you want. It's better, but more complicated to implement.

You'll have to make a judgment call about traffic -- if your traffic could handle a polling call every five seconds from every user, that's the much easier option. If not, websockets it is.

Comment: Please don't forget the scaling fact. If you have 1000 users polling it can easily kill your application.

Comment: Okay thanks! 
Since I have not yet found any other way to go about this, I'll stick to websockets.